# Run Angular tests without the CLI?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-webpack

Given a typical Angular CLI generated project, I'd like to run tests *without* the CLI (because big-business). I'd like to initiate karma using the Karma CLI. I am using Angular 16.

With my setup, I'm currently getting `Incomplete: No specs found`

Here's what I did:

1. Generated a new Angular CLI project using `ng new`
2. Created my own `karma-sans-ng.conf.js` that does not include the Angular plugins, since they cannot be used outside the CLI. [Most of it was copied from the karma config file generated using the CLI](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configuration), but I had to make some tweaks, which I've annotated below.
3. Created my own `src/test.ts` (since Angular no longer uses this :( )
4. Modified `tsconfig.spec.json` to include `src/test.ts` so I can initialize the test utils when running Karma
5. Compile with `tsc --project .\tsconfig.spec.json`
6. Start Karma with `karma start .\karma-sans-ng.conf.js` - no specs are found

**karma-sans-ng.conf.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    files: [
      //include the test initialization and the actual tests
      {
        pattern: 'out-tsc/spec/test.js',
        type: 'module'
      },
      {
        pattern: 'out-tsc/**/*.spec.js',
        type: 'module'
      }
    ],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-webpack'),  //needed to bundle everything for the browser
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
    ],
    preprocessors: {
       //more webpack stuff needed to bundle everything for the browser
      'out-tsc/spec/test.js': [ 'webpack' ],
      'out-tsc/**/*.spec.js': [ 'webpack' ]
    },
    webpack: {
      plugins: [
        //needed, or Karma gets errors about "process not defined"
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          process: 'process/browser',
        }),
      ]
    },
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/testing-without-cli'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

**test.ts**

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/testing';

import { TestBed, getTestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

declare const __karma__:any;
declare const require: any;

__karma__.loaded = function(){};

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());

const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
//const context = require.context('./', true, /out-tsc\\spec\\.*.spec.js$/); //this doesn't work either
context.keys().map(context);
__karma__.start();
```

**tsconfig.spec.ts**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

In older versions of Angular, the `test.ts` file would be generated by the CLI, but this kind of stuff appears to now be managed in `angular.json`. Is my problem that the line that identifies the files is looking in the wrong place?